# Why does thrusting towards a target in orbit make you go farther away from it?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

In the movie *Gravity*, there is a scene where the protagonist aims a Soyuz space craft towards a space station and engages thrust and eventually reaches that station. Many scientists have chimed in that this impossible, and that thrusting towards the target in the way depicted in the movie would actually make you go farther away from it.

Why is that?